# How to get location of currently selected Installed JRE?

Tags: eclipse, java

As you know in Eclipse there is a way to specify the preferred JRE to use (Windows | Preferences | Java | Installed JREs). 
So I need to get the location of currently selected JRE as a preferred. How can I do that? The similar questions on this site are with no proper answers and it is not seams easy to find what I need in Eclipse forums.

I'm developing plugin for Eclipse and, I guess,  there should be specific set of APIs to work with Eclipse preferences but can not figure out how to find it.

Update: I need to get the location programmatically, from my own plugin. And it should work for Windows and Linux.

Comment: I have got the glue - InstanceScope! Hope to find some examples.

Comment: WOW, I have found what I needed - http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipsePreferences/article.html

Comment: One more useful thing - http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/platform-core/documents/user_settings/faq.html#basicGet

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this registry key (on Windows):

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment

You can use `RegOpenKey()` and `RegQueryValueEx()` to query the key/value you need.

Comment: As I mentioned I need to get whatever is defined by Eclipse using Eclipse APIs.